# numerically solve quadratic air drag in xy-plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to find a reference on solving for the position of a point mass as a function time, subject to air drag( quadratic term only) in both the x and y directions. The equations that describe the motion are the following:

[image]

[image]

I know that this system of equations must be solved numerically, but I do not have the experience. I would like to solve this numerically in Java. Can someone  reference me to a method of solving such a system?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, something like that. Specifically something like the Runge-Kutta method, since you can achieve a lower margin of error than with Euler.

Comment: No answers to this?